# Is it possible to align objects on multiple artboards simultaneously in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, artboard

In Illustrator documents like in the example below, I place images on multiple artboards and then need to centre align all of the images to each artboard. I usually do this by clicking the top left image to 'select' the artboard I want to align to, then select all of that row and then vertical centre align. Then repeat this for all other rows and then for columns. Is there a better way to do this?

Images are always the size of the artboard and all the same sized image (ignore that they might not be the same size here or multiples of the same image.)

[image]

Comment: This can be scripted yes. But wouldnt it be more efficient if the script places the images and ceates the artboard based on a image selection?

Comment: Curious if there is a reason you're using Illustrator instead of Indesign for this?  Indesign can do this much more efficiently.

Comment: .... or even a layer stack in Photoshop... Illustrator seems like the *least* efficient app to use.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can drop all the images in illustrator and align them. and select the artboard tool and keep clicking on the image. it will automatically take the size of the image.

InDesign would be the best program to do it. Would recommend that!

Comment: I didn't know we could do that. Great.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest I've found is doing it by rows. Like, select all in a line, then center. It's important the artboards are aligned with each other. I do vertical all together then horizontal all together. Def saves time but isn't perfect. Still 9 or 10 steps instead of dovens [image]